# Twig function with needs_context

Tags: twig, slim

I need to get `current_page` in `needs_context` of my function.
It's working correctly, but `needs_context` stays empty.

**My class Helper extends \Twig_Extension**

```
class Helpers extends \Twig_Extension {

public function getName() {
    return 'Helpers';
}

public function getFunctions() {
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('activeClass', [
            $this,
            'activeClass'
        ], [
            'needs_context' => true
        ])
    ];
}

  public function activeClass($context, $page) {
    if (isset($context['current_page']) && $context['current_page'] === $page){
        return ' active ';
    }
}
```

**In my .twig file**
`<a href="" class="{{ activeClass('foo') }}">Foo</a>`

I hope with this function to return `active` class for the current href in the navbar. I use Slim v3 with his extension Twig-view.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `current_page`? What do you mean that `needs_context` stays empty?

Comment: Hi @martias
1) `current_page` is a key in `needs_context` array and it return the current page. 2) If i do `vardump($context)`, it return nothing. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand what you are trying to do. I think that `needs_context` isn't an array, it's an option whose value is `true` or `false`. It tells the Twig function (`activeClass`) whether or not you need to access the current context in the function. And if `var_dump($context)` displays nothing, where is `current_page` stored? Plus, what is `'foo'` in `{{ activeClass('foo') }}`?

Comment: 1) You are right, `needs_context` is not a array. However if it's at true, it return a array in the callaback. In this array, we have the key `current_page` who return the current page our website.

2) `foo` is the value of the argument $name in my function *activeClass*

If you want, look at the tutorial that I follow. Sorry it's in french, but it's will be more easy for you understand me.
[Tutorial Twig in Youtube](https://youtu.be/mpTtPt62s_w?t=52m28s)

Comment: I edited my main post for to be more clear.

Comment: `var_dump(array_keys($context))`, what does this do?

Comment: Hi @DarkBee and thank,
`var_dump(array_keys($context))` return me `array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "_title" }`

Comment: How are u passing the variable `$current_page` towards `twig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem.
Because I use a extension of Twig for Slim and no Twig, it's different.
Normaly, we use `needs_context` to extract the value of the `current_page`.
But with Twig-view for Slim PHP, we can use `{% if is_current_path('your_page') %}class="active"{% endif %}`

Sincere thanks to @martias and @DarkBee for their help.

Comment: Glad that you resolved the problem! Make sure to choose your answer as the solution. :-) You can also do `{{ is_current_path('your_page') ? 'class="active"' }}`. It's the same as `{{ is_current_path('your_page') ? 'class="active"' : '' }}`.